# Prompt user to retry password when unsuccessful in cx_Oracle connect method

Tags: python, authentication, passwords, connect, cx-oracle

I ma using the cx_Oracle module in python to connect and query an oracle database.

```
import cx_Oracle
```

I have built a tkinter widget so the user can be prompted for their username and password which, in turn, will get passed into the user/password portion of the connect method:

```
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
db = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@//random.company:1234/db1.company.com'.format(username, password))
```

This all works well when the user inputs their correct username and password in the first try however when they don't, I need some logic to iteratively re-try their username and/or password.

The error that is thrown when the wrong credentials are entered is this:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon
>   denied

I've been digging around the interweb for a while now and I can't really seem to find something that works for me. It seems like a lot of the things I've come across involves checking username and passwords against a known dictionary or something along those lines. I don't have the luxury of doing that. I'm probably at a point where I am over thinking this anyways, so I wanted to post up. I feel like it's just some sort of easy 'while' loop I need. Something like:

```
while connection_throws_error_:
    keep_trying_to_log_in
```

Here is my general code:

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import cx_Oracle, pprint

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Username").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Password").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master, fg = 'red', show="*")

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Login', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

master.title("MEMPRD Login")
master.mainloop()

# This is where I need to iteratively prompt user to enter crentials if they are incorrect.
db = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@//random.company:1234/db1.company.com'.format(e1.get(), e2.get())
```

***UPDATE***

Thanks to Alex below, I've used his code, made a few customizations for my own use and it works. Here's the working code:

```
master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Username").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Password").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master, fg = 'red', show="*")

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Login', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
#Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)



master.title("Login")
master.mainloop()

#show_entry_fields()



print e1.get()
print e2.get()

while True:
    try:
        db = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@//random.company:1234/db1.company.com'.format(e1.get(), e2.get())
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        error, = e.args
        if error.code == 1017:
            print('Please check your credentials.')
            e2.delete(0, 'end')
            master.mainloop()        
        else:        
            raise
    else:
        print 'success!'
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it would look in a simple console application:

```
while True:
    username = input('Username:')
    password = getpass('Password:')
    try:
        db = cx_Oracle.connect('{0}/{1}@//random.company:1234/db1.company.com'.format(username, password))
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        # I'm guessing here, you will have to inspect the exception to decide
        # how to check what kind of error it is
        if 'username/password invalid' in e.message.lower(): 
            print('Invalid login')
        else:
            raise
    else:
        print('Success!')
        break
```

I don't know how tkinter works so you will probably have to restructure it for that, but the point is to use try/except in a loop.

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is looking more like what I was envisioning. I had a feeling I had to incorporate some try and except statements in the while loop as well. I'll report back on how this worked for me, but it seems like after all this login testing, I've locked myself out of my oracle account!